# How to overlay two picturebox c# but the picturebox in the background can be seen

Tags: c#

Good day

i don't know if my title is correct. sorry for my bad english

How to overlay two picturebox using c# inoder to achieve the image below, and change the opacity of upper picture box on runtime.

what i need to achieve is something like this. i have two images and i need to overlay them

first image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVSB8.png)

and i have second image with a text of: Another Text on image.
and the location of the text is lower than the text location of the first image
(i can't upload more than two image because i don't have 10 reputation yet.)

i need to do like on the image below, but using two picturebox and can change the opacity in order for the second picturebox below the first one to be seen

and the output of the two image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiLwl.png)

i created the output image using java. i know that i can run the jar file using c#. but the user required to changed the opacity on run time. so how can i do this?

this is the java code i used

BufferedImage biInner = ImageIO.read(inner);
        BufferedImage biOutter = ImageIO.read(outter);

```
    System.out.println(biInner);
    System.out.println(biOutter);

    Graphics2D g = biOutter.createGraphics();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
    int x = (biOutter.getWidth() - biInner.getWidth()) / 2;
    int y = (biOutter.getHeight() - biInner.getHeight()) / 2;
    System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
    g.drawImage(biInner, x, y, null);
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(biOutter, "PNG", new File(output));
```

i hope my question is understandable. thank you

Comment: Sample https://raviranjankr.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/change-opacity-of-image-in-c/

Comment: ill try that. thank you

Comment: i tried the code on the link you posted sir. and i put a picturebox on top of it with the same size. but the picturebox has different image. then i tried to run the program. but i can't see the picturebox below. i even changed the transparency of picturebox on top but can't see the image below. how can i achieve it? thank you

Comment: There is no transparency in .net control. You must use wpf to do that. Sample above is just set the transparency of image not the control.

Comment: Use 1 picturebox, use event paint, and you can draw your image like what you have done in your code

Comment: Either Draw the stuff yourself, or, if the PictureBoxes all can have the same size: __Nest__ them __all__: `pb3.Parent=pb2; pb2.Parent=pb1; pb1.Parent=pb0;`..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just a sample, but blueBox is transparent (0.5):

```
  public sealed partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private readonly Bitmap m_BlueBox;
    private readonly Bitmap m_YellowBox;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DoubleBuffered = true;
      m_YellowBox = CreateBox(Color.Yellow);
      m_BlueBox = CreateBox(Color.Blue);
      m_BlueBox = ChangeOpacity(m_BlueBox, 0.5f);
    }

    public static Bitmap ChangeOpacity(Image img, float opacityvalue)
    {
      var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
      using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
      {
        var colormatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colormatrix.Matrix33 = opacityvalue;
        var imgAttribute = new ImageAttributes();
        imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height,
          GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute);
      }
      return bmp;
    }

    private static Bitmap CreateBox(Color color)
    {
      var bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);
      for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
      {
        for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
          bmp.SetPixel(x, y, color);
        }
      }
      return bmp;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_YellowBox, new Point(10, 10));
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_BlueBox, new Point(70, 70));
    }
  }
```